# OpenCV cv2.imshow() function keep running in Jupyter Notebook using python 3

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I just start to learn OpenCV in Python and mainly use jupyter notebook. The sample I learnt comes from course https://pythonprogramming.net/loading-images-python-opencv-tutorial/

I load an image using cv2.imread() and want to show it up using cv2.imshow(). The image was shown successfully but the program keeps running and can't be interrupted.

May I know why?

Please check following codes:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

img=cv2.imread('sample1.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows() # This part of code keeps running.
```

Comment: `cv2.waitKey(0)` will keep the code running until you bring focus to the image popup and press a key. It's an old post but maybe someone will find this info useful.